# NodeJS Sequelize Query working with date with timestamp

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In my database table let say "sample_date_table", i have a column named "sample_date".
Now in sample_date_table under sample_date column, i have different values of dates, some has with timestamp and some have not timestamp.

example:

1. with timestamp -> 2023-02-01 18:45:54+08
2. without timestamp -> 2023-04-21 00:00:00+08

Now, my query on postgreSQL is working to select those records without timestamp:

```
-- dates without timestamp
SELECT  *
FROM "sample_date_table"
WHERE date_trunc('day', "sample_date ")::timestamp = "sample_date";
```

Now, what i want is to convert this to sequelize, without using raw query and literals.

How to do that ?

or if any much better solution to this one, i will appreciate. thank you